# How to remove querysting token of version generator using bundles in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Hi i m using mvc4 application and using bundles to render scripts and css

below is how i created the bundle:

```
bundles.Add( new StyleBundle( "~/Content/css" ).Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css",
                    "~/Content/site.css" ) );
```

Now it generates the bundle like this as i see in browser source:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=8HZAB6C8ZnrIPYNFzMQKt0AR4AUsUYBjxPPkbGSRIZo1" rel="stylesheet">
```

What i want is to remove the "v" query string of version in the link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because then browsers would cache stale versions of your bundle, as that query string is the fingerprint for when the contents change.

We do have an item in our backlog to make it possible to customize how the fingerprint will show up in the url, but currently there's no way to just turn it off.

A simple workaround is to just render out the path to your bundle explicitly since that will not change if you don't want the query string.

Comment: Did the ability to customize the fingerprint make it into v.1.1.0?

Answer (score 6):

I have created an extension for the mvc-bundling, that enables you to move the querystring part inside the url instead. It can generate urls like this

/bundles/css/20130315191550.css

/bundles/css/_NNIf4XxdPCITzjlKPMgZwHMSUsPyxxGaNCIe6mgAkg1

Code available at http://github.com/unger/Bundling.Extensions

Maybe this can give you some idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up doing the followings:

First I changed the default `BundleResolver` with this implementation

```
public class ReplaceQueryStringBundlerResolver : IBundleResolver
        {
            private readonly IBundleResolver _resolver;

            public ReplaceQueryStringBundlerResolver(IBundleResolver resolver)
            {
                _resolver = resolver;
            }

            public IEnumerable<string> GetBundleContents(string virtualPath)
            {
                return _resolver.GetBundleContents(virtualPath);
            }

            //The important part, modifies the generated Url
            public string GetBundleUrl(string virtualPath)
            {
                var bundleUrl = _resolver.GetBundleUrl(virtualPath);
                bundleUrl = bundleUrl.Replace("?v=", "/v/");
                return bundleUrl;
            }

            public bool IsBundleVirtualPath(string virtualPath)
            {
                return _resolver.IsBundleVirtualPath(virtualPath);
            }
        }
```

And this can be registered in **RegisterBundles** method like this.

```
 BundleResolver.Current = new ReplaceQueryStringBundlerResolver(BundleResolver.Current);
```

Which basically instructs the current resolver to use our needed **Url** format.

This solution is better because we don't have to change `Styles.Render` or `Scripts.Render` calls anywhere in the calling code.

Since we need to map these new bundling `Urls` to the bundles tables, I tried to do something similar with the current Api, but I couldn't get it working so as a temporary solution I added the rewrite rules in the web.config so we can rewrite `/v/` to `?v=`. Ideally the optimization module should do this, since the rewrite rules restrict us to follow some naming conventions and mine is that all bundles virtual paths should start with `"~/bundles/"`

```
<rule name="RewriteBundlesWithNoQueryStrings" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^bundles/(.*)/v/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/bundles/{R:1}?v={R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteBundlesWithNoQueryStringsToDefault" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^bundles/(.*)/(.*)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/bundles/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If I can hook something in the `BundleHandler` class which handles the bundlings requests, I'll come up with an update.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a simple extension like this:

```
public enum RenderType{Css, Js}
public static class _Extentions
{
    public static string RemoveQueryString(this IHtmlString _HtmlString, RenderType _RenderType){
        string Render = _HtmlString.ToHtmlString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("?v=", "/v/");
        Render = Render.Replace(_RenderType == RenderType.Css ? "\" rel=" : "\"></script>", _RenderType == RenderType.Css ? ".css\"  rel=" : ".js\"></script>");
        return Render;
    }      
}
```

And use url rewriting like this:

```
<rule name="rewrite css" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^css/v/(.+).css"/>
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"/>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/css?v={R:1}"/>
</rule> 
<rule name="rewrite js" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^js/v/(.+).js"/>
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"/>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/js?v={R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

and use it this way:

```
<%=Styles.Render("~/css").RemoveQueryString(RenderType.Css)%>
<%=Scripts.Render("~/js").RemoveQueryString(RenderType.Js)%>
```

Please note that the virtual path in the Render function and the one in the url rewriting must match:

Scripts.Render("~/**js**").RemoveQueryString(RenderType.Js)

match url="^**js**/v/(.+).js"